# Keep last option unchanged in multiselectlist even if user clicks to check/uncheck it

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to prevent user from unchecking last option from multiselectlist. Is there any way to do it?

```
$("#multiselectlist").on("change", function () {

       //Keep last option selected, even if user tries to unselect it

        }
    })
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post your HTML.

Comment: Are you using a checkbox for multiselection or default <select> with multi-select!!

Answer (score 0):

you can add the **checked** and  **disabled** attributes to your input. beware that using "readonly" will not work in this case

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using `input` tags. Just in case, this should work either way:

```
$('#multiselectlist').children().last().prop('disabled', true);
```